# Will deportation from Romania harm my chances of getting a UK Study visa?

Tags: uk, study, pakistani-citizens, romania, deportation

Last year I travelled from Pakistan To Romania on work permit But in Romania there was no physical existence of company therefore I can't work there.(Company was only registered to issue work permits). Therefore I tried illegally to enter in schengen zone but during this I was caught and Romania government deported me to my home country Pakistan but on my passport there was a stamp of exit not deport.
Now I'm trying to go to UK for study LLM. Is there any chance for my UK visa rejection due to my previous deport form Europe or not?
Plz guide me.
Thanks

Comment: Your breach of Schengen rules isn’t automatic grounds for refusal for a UK visa but it is obviously a big red flag and definitely won’t help. No-one can tell you for sure however, the only way to find out is to apply.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any chance for my UK visa rejection

Yes.  There is always a chance for a visa rejection.